# Android setting alarm to do a certain part of an activity

Tags: android, random, alarmmanager, alarm, repeat

I'm new to Java and this is my first post on here so hopefully someone can help me. I've checked every website that came up in google to find the answer to this with no luck. So I am trying to set up a repeating alarm that generates a random number every 24 hours from the set time. I am using alarm manager and can only seem to find code examples of using alarm manager to start activities or services. What I want to do is use alarm manager to run a simple command thats already inside of an activity. (If theres another way to do this please let me know)

Here is an example of what I have and what im trying to accomplish

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class ExampleCode extends Activity 
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);           // Here I want to set an alarm      

        Calendar twentyFourHourCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();       


        twentyFourHourCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);                                 // At midnight
        twentyFourHourCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        twentyFourHourCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent someIntent = new Intent("com.example.SomeOtherProcess");                       // Instead of an activity I want it to run the generateRandom() method below

        someIntent.putExtra("NotifID", 1);                                

        PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            getBaseContext(), 0, someIntent, 0);               

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                twentyFourHourCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, twentyFourHourCalendar               // I want it to generate a random number every midnight without any user interaction
                .getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, displayIntent);        

   }



    public void generateRandom()                                                                // This is the method that I want to repeat
    {
        Random generator = new Random(); 
          int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(2);
    }



    }
```

All I want to do is call the generateNumber() method every twenty four hours I'm sure the solution is very simple I think Ive been looking at the code too long to figure it out lol. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: so you just want to call `generateRandom()` from Activity every 24 hrs, is it?

Comment: Basically yes, I might add some more things to do but I don't know what the proper way of doing this would be. Im seeing a lot of broadcast receiver examples but I'm wondering if there is a different way to do it. If using a Broadcast Reciever is the proper way to do it then let me know, like I said I'm new to all of this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try this one  code

```
public class Add_todo_list extends Activity {
    protected static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;
    private int mHour;
    private int mMinute;
    private int aY;
    private int aMo;
    private int aD;
    private int aH;
    private int aMi;


    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getRecords();
        super.onResume();
    }

    Button save, clear, back, cat_add;
    EditText title, disc, due_date, alarm_time;
    Spinner category;
    ToggleButton alarm_set;
    RadioGroup priority;
    RadioButton r1, r2, r3;
    private Database_creat mDbHelper;
    private Alarm_set alarmset;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.todo_add);

        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_Bnt_Save);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_Bnt_clear);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_Bnt_back);
        cat_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_Bnt_category_add);

        title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_edt_title);
        disc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_edt_description);
        due_date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_edt_due_date);
        alarm_time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_edt_alaram_time);
        category = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_spin_category);
        alarm_set = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_togbnt);
        priority = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_RadGro_priority);
        r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_Red_hige);
        r2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_Rad_medium);
        r3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.todo_add_Rad_low);

        mDbHelper = new Database_creat(Add_todo_list.this);
        mDbHelper.Open();
        alarmset = new Alarm_set();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
        getRecords();
        category.setAdapter(adapter);
        category.setPrompt("Category");

        //Date editText box display date dialog box 
        due_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
        //Time editText box display Time dialog box 
        alarm_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        aD = mDay;
        aY = mYear;
        aMo = mMonth;
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        updateDisplay();

        // Add new Category 
        cat_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Add_todo_list.this,
                        Add_new_category.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //Bace button go to Main Activity 
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });
        clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                title.setText("");
                disc.setText("");
                updateDisplay();
            }
        });

        // Save Button to DataBase in Save info
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                String a = title.getText().toString().trim();
                String b = disc.getText().toString().trim();
                String c = due_date.getText().toString().trim();
                String d = alarm_time.getText().toString().trim();
                String e = category.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String f = alarm_set.getText().toString();
                String g = getradio(priority.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance()
                        .format(new Date());
                // Log.v("save", g+" ");
                Intent intent;
                if (a.length() != 0 && b.length() != 0 && mYear >= aY && mMonth >= aMo && mDay >= aD) {
                    // if(c currentDateTimeString){
                    mDbHelper.insert_todoinfo(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
                    Toast.makeText(Add_todo_list.this, "Add New Note ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                     finish();

                    // DateFormat formatter;
                    // Date date = null;
                    // formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
                    // try {
                    // date = (Date) formatter.parse(c);
                    // } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    // e1.printStackTrace();
                    // }

                     // Alarm Set Save with
                    Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.getId(c, d);
                    int getid = 0;
                    Log.v("cursor", "" + cursor.getCount());
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String id = cursor.getString(0);
                        getid = Integer.parseInt(id);
                    }
                    alarmset = new Alarm_set();
                    alarmset.Alarmset(Add_todo_list.this, c, d, getid);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Add_todo_list.this,
                            "Enter Title,Discription and Velid Date ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();    
        }
    };

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mHour = hourOfDay;
            mMinute = minute;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                    mDay);

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, 0, 0, false);

        }
        return null;
    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        due_date.setText("");
        alarm_time.setText("");
        due_date.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-")
                .append(mYear));
        alarm_time.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(mHour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(mMinute)));



    }

    private Object pad(int x) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (x >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(x);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(x);

    }

    //Get List of Category
    private void getRecords() {
        // arrayList.clear();
        adapter.clear();
        Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.getInfoRecords();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cursor.getString(0);
            String Categore = cursor.getString(1);
            adapter.add(Categore);
        }
    }

    //RedioButton Select to get Radio String 
    private String getradio(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String ab = null;
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.todo_add_Rad_low:
            ab = r3.getText().toString();
            break;
        case R.id.todo_add_Rad_medium:
            ab = r2.getText().toString();
            break;
        case R.id.todo_add_Red_hige:
            ab = r1.getText().toString();
            break;
        }
        return ab;
    }
}
```

and other one class

```
public class Alarm_set extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
   //Set Alarm 
    public void Alarmset(Context cont, String c, String d, int getid) {
        Log.v("alaramiuughuhuiohioh", "dfdd");

        int cd = 0, cy = 0, cmo = 0, ch = 0, cmi = 0, cm = 0;
        String date = c.substring(3, 5);
        String month = c.substring(0, 2);
        String Year = c.substring(6, 10);
        String min = d.substring(3, 5);
        String hours = d.substring(0, 2);
        Log.v("get ste", date + "-" + month + "-" + Year);

        cd = Integer.parseInt(date);
        cy = Integer.parseInt(Year);
        cm = Integer.parseInt(month);
        cmo = cm - 1;
        ch = Integer.parseInt(hours);
        cmi = Integer.parseInt(min);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(cy, cmo, cd, ch, cmi);
        Log.v("set", cy + "-" + cd + "-" + cmo + "-" + ch + "-" + cmi);
        Log.v("alarm set", "alarm set in " + cal.getTimeInMillis());

        Intent intent = new Intent(cont, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id",getid);
        PendingIntent penintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cont, getid,
                intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alm = (AlarmManager) cont.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), penintent);

    }

    //Delete Alarm 
    public void Alarmcancel(Context cont, int id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(cont, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
        PendingIntent penintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cont, id, intent,
                0);
        penintent.cancel();
        //Toast.makeText(cont, "alarm stop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

and broadcast class

```
public class AlarmReceiverActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final int MODE_WORLD_READABLE = 0;
    private NotificationManager nm;
    private Database_creat mDbHelper;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String descr = null;
        mDbHelper = new Database_creat(context);
        mDbHelper.Open();
        int id = intent.getIntExtra("id",0);
        Log.v("alarmreciev Id ",id+"");
        String sub_id = String.valueOf(id);
        String alarm_set = null;
        String title = null ;
        SharedPreferences myPrefs;

        // Get Title,Description And Set Status Bar Notifications
        Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.getdata_disp(id);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String Title = cursor.getString(0);
            String Description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description"));
             alarm_set =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("alarm_set"));
             title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));

            descr = Description;
        }

         nm = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

              CharSequence from = "To Do List";
              Intent disintent = new Intent(context,Todo_display_win.class);

              disintent.putExtra("id",sub_id);
              Log.v("send to display Id", sub_id);
              CharSequence message = title;
              Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.notes,
                        "To do List", System.currentTimeMillis());
              notif.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

              PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                      disintent,Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

              notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
              nm.notify(1, notif);
              //nm.cancel(1);
              //notif.defaults |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;




              if(alarm_set.equals("on"))
              {
                  Toast.makeText(context,title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }

              myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
              String on = "on";
                Log.v("sound", myPrefs.getString("sound", "off"));
                if (on.equals(myPrefs.getString("sound", "off"))) {
                    notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                }
                Log.v("vibrate", myPrefs.getString("vibrate", "off"));
                if (on.equals(myPrefs.getString("vibrate", "off"))) {
                    notif.defaults |=Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                } 
                Log.v("light", myPrefs.getString("light", "off"));
                if (on.equals(myPrefs.getString("light", "off"))) {
                    notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
                } 
    }

    }
```

Comment: So you suggest using a Broadcast Reciever to do what I want. This is going to be worded bad but I am fairly new to this stuff so is a Broadcast Reciever BASICALLY an activity that the user does not see or interact with, that fires off it's code when it is called?